# macOS: Changing the wallpaper automatically based on dark/light mode

Tags: macos, catalina, wallpaper

I have some custom wallpapers I use on my Mac. I have some wallpapers which fit best in dark mode, while others in light mode.

Is there a way to set wallpaper x for dark mode, and wallpaper y for light mode? If yes, how could I do that?